# What is the difference between import static java.lang.Math.* and import static java.lang.Math.sqrt

Tags: java

I'm bit eager to know the difference between import static java.lang.Math.* and import static java.lang.Math.sqrt.

I know, Math.* allow us to access all the static methods from Math class. Whereas Math.sqrt provides an access to one and only method sqrt.

Is this the only difference? If I use only sqrt() in my code, what is the best practice to use. Should I use

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
(OR)
import java.lang.Math;
```

As per me, I would go for import static java.lang.Math.sqrt; as I use only sqrt() in my code.
Seems it's silly question. But, need to know good practice. So, posting here.

Comment: You don't need to import `java.lang.Math`, or any part of `java.lang`.

Comment: The code block in your question says `import java.lang.Math;`, which would be unnecessary and does not seem to be what the rest of your question is asking about.

Comment: Agreed Khelwood. I don't need to import java.lang packages as that is implicit import. For reference I took java.lang.Math class as it's well known to everyone.

Comment: Hello @venky
I was wondering if you had time to check my answer.
If you find it useful please upvote it and / or mark it as final answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't specifically need to import java.lang.Math, or any part of java.lang, and your snippet maybe contains some copy / paste errors, as explained in the comment by khelwood.

If we want to think about a more generic question on the topic if you are importing the whole class you are using more memory and if you are not using all the imported methods it doesn't make sense to import it all, it would be just a waste of resources.

Using an advanced IDE like IntelliJ you can enable automatic import and code analysis and this kind of best practises will be automatically suggested and enforced in your code with warnings and errors provided directly from the IDE.
My suggestion is adopting a similar solution because it will speed up and improve your coding right away.

Or, if you don't like the idea of automatic import, you can use the Optimize Import function and obtain a similar result with a simple shortcut (control + alt + o).

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The general way to introduce classes: `import java.lang.Math.*;`

The way to introduce classes statically: `import static java.lang.Math.*;`

**The difference is that:**

Generally, the introduction requires the use of `ClassName.method();` to call the static method in the class;

```java
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(Math.sqrt(4)); //Need to add the class name prefix
     }
}
```

After static introduction, use `method();` directly to use static method.

```java
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(sqrt(4)); //Call the method directly
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use only function sqrt, you should import package static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
if you use other function of java Math, you should import all : java.lang.Math.
but import java.lang.Math.* leading to more memory overhead

Comment: `sqrt` is a (static) Method, not a package. And you cannot really import parts of a class. There is no difference in memory here. Mentioning a single method name only makes sense in combination with [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

Classes are imported as a whole, there is no need to mention a method name or an asterisk.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Classes from package `java.lang` don't need to be imported:

```
package world;
// no imports needed

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        double a = 3;
        double b = 4;
        double c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2));
        System.out.println(c);
    }    
}
```

However, if you need to use lots of methods from that class, it can get a bit tedious to repeat the class name. Therefore, java provides a feature named [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html)

Using this, you can choose specific methods or constants for which you want to omit the class name

```
import static java.lang.Math.pow;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        double a = 3;
        double b = 4;
        double c = Math.sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)); //explicit Math.sqrt, implicit Math.pow
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
```

or all methods of a class

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        double a = 3;
        double b = 4;
        double c = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2));
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}
```

Important caution from the [official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html):

> So when should you use static import? **Very sparingly!** Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern).

So, answering your specific question:

---

Only use

```
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
```

if you want to be able to omit the class name when using it.

In all other cases, just omit the import statement.